# Как собрать строку в интерполяторе?

Tags: javascript, строки, ecmascript-6

ES6 вводит интерполируемые строки. Но помимо интерполяции с ними есть интересная возможность - [преобразование подставляемых значений](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Не знаю, для чего оно задумывалось, но лично мне кажется логичным использовать его для некого преобразования всех подставляемых значений. Например, для экранирования символов. Конечно же, я могу написать соответствующий код:

```js
function toUrl(s, ...vals) {
  vals = vals.map(encodeURIComponent);

  /// ???
  var res = '';

  for (var q=0; q<vals.length; ++q) {
    res += s[q] + vals[q];
  }

  return res + s[s.length-1];
}

var data='a+b', args='%'
console.log(toUrl `data=${data}&args=${args}`)
console.log(toUrl `data=${data}&args=${args}&t=1`)
```

Однако, меня несколько удивляет необходимость вручную писать кусок кода, находящийся после `???`. Все кажущиеся мне естественными применения этой фичи требуют подобный код и при этом я не смог найти стандартный метод, который бы объединил строки с обработанными аргументами. Есть ли такой метод? А если его действительно нет, то возникает вопрос, а для чего же на самом деле задумывалась эта фича?

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/q/39583660/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39583660/4928642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `???` можно воспользоваться функцией `String.raw`.

```
function toUrl(s, ...vals) {
  vals = vals.map(encodeURIComponent);
  return String.raw({ raw: s }, ...vals);
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, такой способ делает не совсем то что нужно. Ваш первый вариант был лучше.

Comment: Ага, я уже нашёл проблему. Вернул первый вариант.